# Show/hide markers from categories with infobubble

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have markers belonging to multiple categories, and I'd like to be able to hide/show markers based on categories using checkboxes. I've had the checkboxes working without the infowindow attached, but now that I attached the infowindow, the checkboxes do not work anymore. I think the show and hide functions cannot access arrMarkers.category somehow, because all the markers are visible when I comment out `marker.setVisibile(false)`. But with that line, somehow the first marker is still visible, while all the others are not....

Here's my code, if someone could explain to me why its not working, that would be great:

```
var markerData = [
                ['blueforce1', 52.308584, 4.767637, 1, 'yellow', 'yes'],
                ['blueforce2', 52.308656, 4.76517, 1, 'yellow', 'yes'],
                ['blueforce3', 52.308656, 4.72517, 1, 'yellow', 'yes'],
                ['blueforce4', 52.309686, 4.762734, 2, 'red', 'yes'],
                ['blueforce5', 52.309463, 4.771693, 2, 'red', 'yes'],
                ['blueforce6', 52.309963, 4.771693, 2, 'red', 'yes'],
                ['camera7', 52.308656, 4.76517, 3, 'camera', 'no'],
                ['blueforce8', 52.318656, 4.73517, 3, 'camera', 'no'],
            ];

function initialize()
        {
            var arrMarkers = [];

            var mapProp = { //set map properties
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(52.309213,4.762316),
                    zoom:16,
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                    };

            //create map variable with properties       
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
for (i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData[i][1], markerData[i][2]);
                var title = markerData[i][0];
                var category = markerData[i][3];
                var new_marker = addMarker(pos, title, category);
                arrMarkers.push(new_marker);
                //new_marker[i].setVisible(false);
            }

            function addMarker (pos, title, category) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    icon: "mapIcons/marker_"+markerData[i][4]+".png",
                    category: category

                });  

                var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                    content: '<div class="phoneytext">' + title + '<div class="left-col2"></div></div>',
                    boxClass: 'info-box',
                    alignBottom: true,
                    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-150, -40),
                    maxWidth: 300,
                    padding: 0,
                    closeBoxMargin: '0px',
                    borderColor: '#ffffff',
                    borderRadius: '0',
                    maxWidth: 535,
                    disableAutoPan: false,
                    hideCloseButton: false,
                    backgroundClassName: 'phoney'
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { 
                    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                    //console.log(infoBubble.content);
                });

                return marker;
            }






            //define click action for id 'open'
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('open'),'click', function() {
                                infoBubble.open();
                                });

                //define click action for id 'closed'               
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('close'),'click', function() {
                                infoBubble.close();
                                });

        }//end of initialize

            // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
            function show(category) {
                for (var i=0; i<arrMarkers.length; i++) {
                    if (arrMarkers[i].category == category) {
                        arrMarkers[i].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
                // == check the checkbox ==
                document.getElementById("cat"+category).checked = true;
            }

            // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
            function hide(category) {
                for (var i=0; i<arrMarkers.length; i++) {
                    if (arrMarkers[i].category == category) {
                        arrMarkers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
                // == clear the checkbox ==
                document.getElementById("cat"+category).checked = false;
                // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
                //infowindow.close();
            }

            // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
            function boxclick(box,category) {
                if (box.checked) {
                    show(category);
                }
                else {
                    hide(category);
                }
                }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    Blue Forces cat 1: <input type="checkbox" id="cat1" onclick="boxclick(this, 1)" checked/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    Blue Forces cat 2: <input type="checkbox" id="cat2" onclick="boxclick(this, 2)" checked/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    Cameras: <input type="checkbox" id="cat3" onclick="boxclick(this, 3)" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
```

Comment: the markers did not have a category - property at all, you forgot to add it in `addMarker()`

Comment: Ok, but then I wouldn't know where to put it (based on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)? I thought that pushing the category to the arrMarker array would be enough, since that is where the hide/show functions compare the category...

Comment: A marker may have any property, the API-docs only list the properties needed for the maps-API, but you may also apply custom properties.

Comment: Ok thanks. I updated my code with the category property, but it only worked after I commented out the setVisible(false) line. I made the checkboxes checked, and although it works now, I actually want the starting setup to be without markers and boxes unchecked. Do you know how to change it? Because when I add the setVisisble line again, it breaks down...

Comment: new_marker is not an array, it must be `new_marker.setVisible(false);`. Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/WPvC6/